# Hamcrest.Matchers: JSON Nested Array

Tags: java, json, testng, hamcrest, rest-assured

I have an array as follow: [[Disable,Enable,No,Yes][Joe,Bill,Doug,Kevin],[Red,Blue,Pink,Magenta],[One,Two,Three,Four]];

I need a hamcrest matcher that will match with an excel file that has name/value pair data in it. I have Tried: hasItem,hasItems,hasItemInArray.

I have looked at the following links:

[Hamcrest Link](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial)

Let me know if I am missing any info that would be helpful.

```
private String[][] getExcelSheetData(String excelFile)
        throws NoExcelValidationDataFoundException {
    String[][] excelValidationData = null;

    try {
        ExcelDAOFactory excelDAOFactory = (ExcelDAOFactory) DAOFactory
                .getFactory(DAOFactory.EXCEL);
        excelDAOFactory.setExcelFile(excelFile);
        excelValidationData = excelDAOFactory.fetchData();
        TAFLogger.logTAFActivity("Finished retrieving data from "
                + excelFile);
    } catch (InvalidFormatException | IOException | UnsupportedDAOException e) {
        TAFLogger.logTAFActivity(
                "Error retrieving data from ExcelDAOFactory: "
                        + e.getMessage(), logger.WARN);
        throw new NoExcelValidationDataFoundException(
                "Could not retireve validation " + "data from " + excelFile
                        + e.getMessage());
    }
    return excelValidationData;
}
```

Code to try and match with hamcrest, which has nothing for 'Nested Array's which I can see:

```
 requestBuilder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
    requestBuilder.addCookie().setContentType(ContentType.JSON);
    requestSpecification = requestBuilder.build();


    responseBuilder = new ResponseSpecBuilder();
    responseBuilder.expectStatusCode(Integer.parseInt(xmlTest
        .getParameter("http-status-code-200")));
    //responseBuilder.expectContentType(ContentType.JSON);
    responseSpecification = responseBuilder.build();

    try {
        validationData = getExcelSheetData(excelFile);
    } catch (NoExcelValidationDataFoundException e) {
        Logger.logActivity("Could not retrieve Excel sheet data: "
                + e.getMessage(), Logger.ERROR);
        Assert.fail("Could not retrieve Excel sheet data: "
                + e.getMessage());

  for (int i = 0; i < validationData.length; i++) {
  responseBuilder.expectBody(validationData[i][0],
hasItemInArray(validationData[i][1]));

 responseSpecification = responseBuilder.build();

    try {
        //Response res = given().getValue()).get("data/roles");

        String data = given().spec(requestSpecification).
.expect().spec(responseSpecification).when().get("data/roles").asString();
        System.out.println(data);

        logger.logTestActivity("Completed testing JSON payload using Excel    file");
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        logger.logTestActivity(
                "Error testing JSON payload: " + e.getMessage(),
                logger.ERROR);
        throw new Exception(e);
```

The last par with the "hasIteminArray' is where I am trying to utilize Hamcrest to assert on the JSON of a nested array.

Comment: You question is how to test the value in a excel file with hamcrest matcher ? Show some code will be helpful.

Comment: You need to split this problem into two: reading the name/value pairs from Excel into a map, and then building a matcher from this map. For the first, you can use POI. The second part of the problem is more relevant to Hamcrest: can you explain how you expect to match your two-dimensional array against name/value pairs?

Comment: added some code to help understand what I am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no Excel integration included in Hamcrest. [simple-excel](http://baddotrobot.com/blog/2012/09/14/diff-excel-with-java-and-hamcrest/) offers verification of generated excel files and brings it's own Hamcrest matchers for this.

Otherwise you are most likely to have to roll your own matches using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).